# Kmail doesn't always start when using Dolphin's "Send via Email"

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, kmail

Kubuntu 19.10+Kubuntu PPA backports enabled.

Latest updates installed.

Quite often "Send via Email" doesn't do anything.

I see Kmail "opening" at the bottom taskbar, and there is a circle flashing, but then Kmail just disappears.

If I launch Kmail manually and then use "Send via Email" then it always works fine.

Has anyone else experienced this bug?

How can I troubleshoot it?

Thank you.

Comment: Re. "Quite often "Send via Email" doesn't do anything." Approximately how often? Please [edit] the question to add the output of `inxi -SCIz`. It's quite compact so no need of pastebin.